# mi sesion no jala los datos para llenar el gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

creo que mi sesion no esta jalando el dato del gridview para hacer una consulta y agregar un valor en un formulario de una pagina aparte.

este rowcommand es para jalar el dato codigoetq.

```
protected void GvOnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow selected = gvESS.Rows[index];
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["etqss"] = selected.Cells[8].Text;
        Label2.Text = selected.Cells[8].Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Equipos/EqSinSofE.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
```

lo siguiente es este metodo

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        llenarddanti();
        llenarddvwin();
        llenarddetiw();
        llenarddoff();

        if (Session["etqss"] != null)
        {
            tabla = Equipos.GetEqSS(Session["etqss"].ToString());
            llenarcampos(tabla);

            gv2.DataSource = tabla;
            gv2.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

la sesion "etqss" se supone que debe de traer el dato de codigoetq de la fila que se selecciono y hace una consulta para llenar un gridview con este metodo

```
public static DataTable GetEqSS(string etqss)
{
    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
    using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Soporte"].ToString()))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string sql = string.Format("Select codigoetq from Equipo WHERE codigoetq ='{0}'", etqss);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
        tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    }
    return tabla;
}
```

y con esto llenar los datos en el label

```
public void llenarcampos(DataTable tabla)
{
    txtclaeti.Text = tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: No entendi, podrias reformular tu pregunta y agregar primero la idea general de lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: ok lo que quiero hacer es que con el valor que estoy jalando de un campo de un gridview hacer una consulta para asi agregarlo a otro gridview en otra pagina y asi despues ese valor colocarlo en un label o si se pudiera en un hidden

Comment: no se si me explique, es mi primera vez trabajando con asp y no estoy muy familiarizado todavia

Comment: Revisa el siguiente articulo https://www.kyocode.com/2018/11/cargar-datos-gridview-de-datatable-asp-net-c/